# Jmeter - Extracting a a JSON value by validating with another value

Tags: jmeter

It is possible to get a JSON value by validating with another value.
For example i am getting multiple responses as below;

```
{
            "place_name": "Home",
            "selected_icon": "http:\/\/abc.tech\/images\/home_selected.png",
            "updated_at": "2017-11-10 12:12:34.795339",
            "icon": "http:\/\/abctech\/images\/home.png",
            "created_at": "2017-11-10 12:12:34.795339",
            "active_flag": 1,
            "id": 1
        }
```

I have extract the "place name" using $..place_name. Now validating the place_name i need to extract the icon. Which means i need to save the icon value which matches the "place name" only

```
Varibale : new
JSON extractor 1 : $..place_name (second value so only using $..)
Varibale : abc
JSON extractor 2:$..[?(@.place_name==${new})].icon
Matc No (o for random): -1
```

The value is not passing any suggestion

i have tried with this extarctor also JSON extractor 2:$..[?(@.place_name=='${new}')].icon

Match random i am taking as -1 because i am passing the value in for each controller

Answer (score 1):

I don't find any issue with you approach, it is working fine. I have tried with your payload and changed your payload with multiple value. Both are working fine.

With your payload where single `place_name` is there,

[image]

[image]

[image]

With multiple value for `icon`:

[image]

Passed the value to `for each` controller
[image]

[image: ![enter image description here]